# How to apply an image to Widget Background (superimposing)

Tags: python, pyqt

I would like to assign a background image to the widget such as QListWidget or QWidget.
Here is the idea: [image]
[image]

Ideally the background image would resize when its widget size changes. Any ideas how to achieve it?

### EDITED LATER:

Here is screen-capture of the dialog with suggestion made by Salvatore implemented.
If the background image used is PNG then using its layer opacity you can control how much it is visible (faded out). I like it .... Thanks!

[image]

---

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class MyApp(object):    
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__()                
        self.mainWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.mainWidget.setLayout(self.mainLayout)

        self.hLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.mainLayout.insertLayout(0, self.hLayout)
        self.listA=QtGui.QListWidget()
        for i in range(3):
            self.listA.addItem('Item '+str(i))
        self.hLayout.addWidget(self.listA)

        self.buttonGroupbox = QtGui.QGroupBox()
        self.buttonlayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.buttonGroupbox.setLayout(self.buttonlayout)

        okButton = QtGui.QPushButton('OK')
        self.buttonlayout.addWidget(okButton)

        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.buttonGroupbox)
        self.mainWidget.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MyApp()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can set a stylesheet to the target widget :

```
self.listA.setStyleSheet("""
    color: white; 
    background-image: url(./your_image.jpg);
    background-attachment: scroll;
""");
```

but with this code your image don't resize itself.

Comment: I've just posted a screen capture of the result. It works pretty well. The QListWidget() Items styleSheet need to be set or defined as well since the listItems default style values are now being overridden by QListWidget's stylesheet making the Items font light-light-gray (practically white). A bottom line it is doable job. It just would take some extra time to tweak every widget appearance right. Thanks for the info!